# ping domain and write out ip in a csv file

Tags: php, ping

I have a loop where I loop through a number of domains and I ping theme: the loop looks as follows:

```
foreach ($rows[1] as $domains){
$domain='www.'.$domains;
$output = shell_exec('ping -c1 '.$domain.'');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

}
```

My question: is it possible to write out the resultant ip address for each looped domain?

Comment: Since the output of ping depends on your operating system I would recommend using gethostbyname()

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you hoping to learn by pinging "www" hostnames in an array of domains?

Comment: you see maybe is not the best way to do it, I'm still learning new things, we have a lot of domains by our host and I wanted to automatize a bit the procedure after crawling the domain html table from our host to get know if the ip's are ours or the domain has been saled because unfortunately this kind of thing haven't been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) (PHP docs). Example:

```
foreach ($rows[1] as $domains){
   $domain='www.'.$domains;
   $output = shell_exec('ping -c1 '.$domain.'');
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
   echo gethostbyname($domain);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach ($rows[1] as $domains){
    $domain='www.'.$domains;
    $ip = gethostbyname($domain);
    echo $domain.','.$ip.'\n';
}

//OUPUT HEADERS
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=domains.csv;" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```